# OpenCV's cvWriteFrame(..) does nothing

Tags: c++, qt, video, opencv

I spent a few hours trying to write an avi file with `CvVideoWriter`. I always get a file with the size of 5.54KB and no frames in it. I checked if `CvVideoWriter` is not null and it isn't. I also tried to show my IplImage with `cvShowImage` and it displays correctly. I tried multiple codecs (DIVX, H264, ..).

I found out though that the function saves frames in jpg files when VideoWriter is defined like this:

```
CvVideoWriter* recorder = cvCreateVideoWriter("test0001.jpg", CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V'), -1, Size(w,h), true);
```

This is my program:

```
IplImage* myIplFrame=...;
CvVideoWriter* recorder = cvCreateVideoWriter("test.avi", CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V'), 10, Size(w,h), true);

cvShowImage("test",myIplFrame); //showing image properly
cvWriteFrame(recorder, myIplFrame);
cvWaitKey(500); //not helping

cvReleaseVideoWriter(&recorder);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another similar thread on SO concerning this and someone mentioned you should compile with MinGW instead VS. I did that and included new libraries and include path like this in .pro file (Qt):

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\mingwBuild\install\include

LIBS += -LC:\\OpenCV-2.3.1\\opencv\\build\\x86\\mingw\\lib \
    -lopencv_core231 \
    -lopencv_highgui231
```

Notice how I used libraries from `opencv` folder; that is the folder with the sources, after you configure and generate it with CMake for example.

Another hint that you, the reader, have the same problem is if cv::Mat isn't recognised or you get some weird errors about it - *simpleFree* function undefined (or something similar, can't remember anymore) for e.g.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The IYUV codec should be builtin so videowriter can always create files of this type.

You can create a file, so the permissions are correct.

Is there a good reason you are using the old iplimage instead of the cv standard format?
This is the first thing I would check.

See http://docs.opencv.org/

ps. There is no need for the waitkey() if you aren't displaying an image.

Comment: I just figured out I had to recompile OpenCV with MinGW and use libraries from there. I also used the newer format like cv::Mat and newer functions and it's working now (just figured out) :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit- it was a set of suggestions of what to try next which are also useful for people having the same problem